# How to use QML QtWebView to call C++?

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qwebview, qtwebview

With Qt 5.5, using the [Minibrowser example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebview-minibrowser-example.html) they provide, it uses something different than [QWebView widget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebview.html). Instead, it uses QML and a [QtWebView module](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebview-index.html). When you look in Javascript's `navigator.appVersion`, it lets you know that QWebView loads a custom AppleWebKit/538.1 (a thing shipped with Qt5.5), while QtWebView (note the difference) loads the native core OS AppleWebKit/601.1.56. This is confirmed because when I load Safari on my OSX (El Capitan version), it says 601.1.56.

The problem, however, is how can my Javascript functions in Minibrowser call C++ functions on the backend to do more powerful stuff? When I was using the QWebView widget, I was able to use the [C++ webkit bridge](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebkit-bridge.html) that let me inject into the DOM my C++ object and therefore could call my C++ code. I'm not seeing any technique documented for how to do this with the QML-based Minibrowser example that uses QtWebView. What's the technique?

EDIT: Oh, and to clarify, I'm not calling remote web pages with this, via a web server. I'm just calling stuff through file://. In other words, I'm using the rich webkit interface to give me a super powerful GUI that goes way beyond what the Qt widgets and QML can provide for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Basically, in Qt5.5, I'm diving into experimental land with QtWebView. The class methods are largely undocumented and may change in the future.

For now, the only technique is message passing, not native C++ class method invocation like you could use in the [QWebView C++ Bridge](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebkit-bridge.html). The QWebView C++ Bridge only works with QWebView widgets, not the QtWebView QML. So, you do this message passing with `navigator.qt.postMessage()` API from your Javascript to your QML, and then QML can call C++. In order to get that extra functionality, you'll need to do a few steps. Here's an example:

[Invoke C++ method from webviews Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342220/invoke-c-method-from-webviews-javascript)

This is blogged a little here:

http://rschroll.github.io/beru/2013/08/21/qtwebview.experimental.html

As you can see from the example, you have to add these imports to your main.qml:

```
import QtWebKit 3.0
import QtWebKit.experimental 1.0
```

Then, in your `WebView{}` section, you have to add this line:

```
experimental.preferences.navigatorQtObjectEnabled: true
```

At that point, you can call `navigator.qt.postMessage("call foo in C++");` to send a message to the QML, which you can then pick up inside your `WebView{}` section with:

```
experimental.onMessageReceived: { ...do something here in the QML... }
```

Your QML can then pass a message right back to the Javascript with:

```
experimental.postMessage("okay, I called foo in C++")
```

And then in your Javascript you can add an event listener like so:

```
navigator.qt.onmessage = function(ev) {

  $('BODY').prepend(ev.data); // since console.log() is not possible

}
```

As for how to get your QML to call C++, here's an example:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17881019/105539

**EDIT**: After more experimentation in Qt 5.5 with QtWebView, it appears fairly flaky in the following respects. **I don't recommend it in 5.5 -- it's not ready for primetime.** In Qt 5.5, you're better off using the QWebView widget for now and then migrate to [QtWebEngine](http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-dev/qtwebengine-overview.html) when the next version of Qt comes out (Qt 5.6, 5.7?).

- By default, it gives you a rightclick context menu you may not want. Interestingly, you can turn it off if you import the experimental library and then set this property in your QML: `experimental.preferences.navigatorQtObjectEnabled: true`.
- By default, HTML5 postMessage() API (the one native with HTML5) doesn't appear to work unless you enable `experimental.preferences.navigatorQtObjectEnabled: true`.
- When you enable `experimental.preferences.navigatorQtObjectEnabled: true`, the scrollbars disappear if you enabled them on some HTML page elements, the checkboxes and radio buttons look extremely funky, and popdown select listboxes stopped working.
- When you doubleclick a page, it zooms it.

Comment: @MrEricSir I think you might be confused. I was referring to QtWebView being poorly documented, not QWebView. QtWebView ships with 5.5 and only utilizes native webkit APIs, which only ship on Android, iOS, and OSX, but not Windows or Linux. QWebView, on the other hand, ships with 5.5 but comes with an older (but still usable) version of webkit.

Comment: @MrEricSir Also, it appears that QtWebView in 5.5 just isn't usable yet -- stuff breaks, as I explain above. So, one really has no choice but to use QWebView for now, which will only work in 5.5 but will not ship past 5.5, and then migrate to QtWebEngine later. The bad news about QtWebEngine, however, is that it deploys with Chromium instead of Webkit -- a fat install -- and will likely not get you approved in the Apple Store.

Comment: I tried and failed with error message: `"QtWebKit.experimental" is not installed`. Why it this happening? I'm using Qt 5.7.0 on Windows.